# How can I model "Rounds Theater Pavilion"?

Tags: modeling

I am a beginner and need help modelling this structure in Blender.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Draw the profile of your road:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Bevel the edges in order to round (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]

Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 360° on Z, add some edges in order to have something round enough, move the mesh away from its origin if you want to increase the inner radius:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify modifier* to add thickness, enable the *Even Thickness* option:

[image]

Final version with the following modifier stack: *Simple Deform, Weld, Solidify, Bevel, Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use *Bezier Curve* ... start with *Circle*, *Subdivide* few times, few control points move up on Z axis ...

[image]

Under Curve *Properties > Geometry* > set **Extrude** and set **Bevel** > *Profile > Resolution* 1 and move middle point to corner to get right angle.

Or instead of *Bevel* use **Solidify** modifier.

Set shading from *Smooth* to **Flat** a nd increase *Resolution* from 12 to **36** (under curve properties).

To orient extrusion in correct direction change **Tilt** to 90° for all points and for points on top of waves set 75°.

[image]

For some control points I changed handle type.

[image]

[image]